# Extracting Private Key from a DER file

Tags: ssl, openssl, der

I have a DER certificate file, and using openssl I tried to extract the private key. I tried many commands but none of them would extract the key. I WAS able to extract the certificate, but not the PK.. Any ideas what to do? Many thanks.

Comment: The type of certificate commonly used (and supported by OpenSSL) contains a public key, and in fact its main purpose is to convey that public key to people and devices that must not receive the private key. Thus the certificate does not contain the private key, so **you cannot** extract it. This is confused sometimes because some systems or programs can store a certificate with the private key attached or linked, and use the name(s) on the cert to (conveniently) access the key, but the key is still separate from and not in the cert. (If the key is _horribly_ weak you might _break_ it.)